# how to do reverse fulltext search in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

By default it's like this:

```
select * from main_table where match(col1,col2) against('search_item');
```

but what I want to fetch is the reverse,

say,I've restored all the search_item(1000 records,for example),

and I want to see which of them matches a specified row in main_table.

Is that doable?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM search_items WHERE (SELECT col1 FROM main_table WHERE ID = XXX) LIKE CONCAT('%',search_item,'%');
```

That is going to be pretty darn slow if you have a huge dataset to get through.

If speed is an issue, another way to handle this (although admittedly a lot more complicated) is to get all of the data out of the database and build yourself a [ternary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search_tree) (also called a trie).  Once you get through the overhead of building the trie, matching against input strings is lightning fast compared to brute force methods.

Comment: no,`like` is not the solution,I need it to be done using the same schema as fulltext search

Answer (score -1):

Well I realise this is ten months late but just for the sake of posterity. I think what you're saying is that you want all rows in the **search_items** table which would *not* match the query :

```
select * from main_table where match(col1,col2) against('search_item');
```

I'm going to assume that your main_table has some unique identifier column which I'll call unqid.

```
select * from main_table
WHERE
unqid not in (select unqid 
              from main_table  
              where match(col1,col2) against('search_item')
             )
```

My first thought was to use a MINUS operator but it turns out MySQL doesn't have one !